# How to determine SMIME Version for Bouncycastle 155

Tags: encryption, version, bouncycastle, smime

I'm decrypting and removing the signature of signed and encrypted (email) messages. A client asked for the supported SMIME versions and that's where I'm stuck.
I use bouncycastle 155. Tried to check the release notes but there are statements like:

(Version 147)
"**RFC 5751** changed the definition of the micalg parameters defined in RFC 3851. The SMIMESignedGenerator is now up to date with the latest micalg parameter set and a constructor has been added to allow the old micalg parameter set to be used."

RFC 5751 describes SMIME Version 3.2. Does bouncycastle fully support SMIME Version 3.2 or just that parameter? What version of SMIME does bouncycastle support?

Thanks for help.